# How can I display a background color change on hover (with a twist)?

Tags: css

I'll get straight to the point.

I have 4 elements (background-1, background-2, background-3, background-4).

When I first arrive on the page I want Background-1 to have "background-color: #D8D7D8;"
and the three others "background-color: #FBFBFB;".
Then whenever I hover another background-x I want all of them to be #FBFBFB except the one being hovered which would be in #D8D7D8.

I know this probably pretty easy for you, but not for me haha.

My css looks like this :

```
.background-1 :hover{
    background: #D8D7D8;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
.background-2 :hover{
    background: #D8D7D8;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
.background-3 :hover{
    background: #D8D7D8;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
.background-4 :hover{
    background: #D8D7D8;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
```

Here is how it looks like : [Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChRZP.jpg)

Thank you in advance !

Milack

Comment: You need to show the basic structure of your HTML.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Richard ! I am working on a wordpress website that is why I didn't give you my html. I can only give classes to my elements (in this case text editors). My css code looks like this for now : 
.background-1 :hover{
    background: #D8D7D8;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
.background-2 :hover{
    background: #D8D7D8;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
.background-3 :hover{
    background: #D8D7D8;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
.background-4 :hover{
    background: #D8D7D8;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}

Comment: The answer will depend on the basic structure of the HTML. We don't need to see the full HTML, but we do need to know whether, for example, the four "background" elements are siblings.

Comment: I am a total newbie so I'll try to answer the best I can. In wordpress I have the possibility to add css ID, css classes and custom css to any elements. In my case I have 4 sections stacked on top of each others. Each section has a css class called "background-X". I could also put them all in the class "background-all" if it helps with the code. Here is what it looks like right now : [Imgur](https://i.imgur.com/CpnXShP.jpg)

Comment: But are those HTML elements siblings? Do they all have the same parent element? *(If you're not sure, [The HTML Document Tree](http://web.simmons.edu/~grabiner/comm244/weekfour/document-tree.html) might help.)*

Comment: I would say yes as the 4 sections are in a column which itself is in a section

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all four elements are siblings, you could do something like below.

For the default `bg1` value, I've suggested a JavaScript event handler.

```js
const divs = document.querySelectorAll('.bg');

function clearBgExcept(target) {
  divs.forEach(div => div.style.backgroundColor = div !== target ? "#FBFBFB" : "#D8D7D8");
}

function clearAllBg() {
  divs.forEach(div => div.style.backgroundColor = div.dataset.default ? "#D8D7D8" : "#F8F8F8" );
}
divs.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('mouseover', e => {
    clearBgExcept(e.target);
  }));
  
divs.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
    clearAllBg();
  }));
```

```css
.wrapper {
  min-width: 300px;
  min-height: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
}

.bg {
  background-color: #FBFBFB;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}

.bg[data-default="true"], .bg:hover {
  background-color: #D8D7D8;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="bg" data-default="true">BG1</div>
  <div class="bg">BG2</div>
  <div class="bg">BG3</div>
  <div class="bg">BG4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! This is exactly what I was looking for. I will try to understand your code and implement it !

Comment: You're welcome. The JavaScript is only there to support the requirement "background 1 is turned on by default." You can remove all JavaScript and everything should work fine, except `BG1` won't be darker shade by default.

Comment: ok ! it's perfect Bumhan ! thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your elements are siblings, then there's no need for Javascript:

```css
.background-1,
.background-2,
.background-3,
.background-4 {
  background-color: #FBFBFB;
  padding: 2em;
}

.background-1 {
  background-color: #D8D7D8;
}

.background-1:hover {
  background: #D8D7D8;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}

.background-2:hover {
  background: #D8D7D8;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}

.background-3:hover {
  background: #D8D7D8;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}

.background-4:hover {
  background: #D8D7D8;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}

.column:hover .background-1:not(:hover) {
  background-color: #FBFBFB;
}
```

```html
<div class="column">
  <div class="background-1">
    B1
  </div>
  <div class="background-2">
    B2
  </div>
  <div class="background-3">
    B3
  </div>
  <div class="background-4">
    B4
  </div>
</div>
```

The only "clever" part is to reset the `background-1` colour when the parent element is hovered but `background-1` is *not* hovered.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I have used your solution in the end ;) I wish you a good week-end